# Robust correlation in python?

Tags: correlation, python, robust

Is some kind of robust (especially to outliers) correlation methods easily available in python? I have a suspicion that outliers might be causing false positives in my data.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Scikit-learn has an implementation of [RANSAC](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.RANSACRegressor.html) and [Theil-Sen regression](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.TheilSenRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.TheilSenRegressor), both commonly used robust estimation methods. You could also fit a linear model via [stochastic gradient descent](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor.html#sklearn.linear_model.SGDRegressor) and choose to optimize a loss function like the Huber loss or \epsilon-insensitive loss, both of which would lead to a robust model.

Once you've fit your model using whatever method you like, you can compute the Pearson correlation on your data using your linear model.

Hope that helps!

Comment: Thanks! I would appreciate a more elaborate explanation on how to use a model to compute correlation...

Comment: Sure, you can compute it from the R^2 value. Sklearn has a scoring function to compute the [coefficient of determination, or R^2](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.r2_score.html#sklearn.metrics.r2_score). This is useful because the [coefficient of determination is the square of the Pearson correlation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coefficient_of_determination).

Comment: Thanks again! I made it work - there is even a method `score` of the model object I could use. But is there a way to get a p-value for this correlation?..

Comment: Anyways, seems like I didn't need to worry about this issue, the values with Theil-Sen are in most cases very close to Pearson. However for the future I would be happy to have a p-value estimate too :)